# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: checkmarkFilterProvider <- checkmarkFilter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a 'ArticleDataFactory' which brings the data. But the components throws the injector error. The error stack is:

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: checkmarkFilterProvider <-checkmarkFilterhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/unpr?p0=checkmarkFilterProvider%20%3C-%20checkmarkFilter
at angular.js:68
at angular.js:4630
at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4783)
at angular.js:4635
at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4783)
at angular.js:20309
at isStateless (angular.js:14959)
at findConstantAndWatchExpressions (angular.js:15017)
at angular.js:14971
at forEach (angular.js:357)
```

The module is defined :

```
'use strict';
 angular.module('articleDetail', ['ngRoute','core.article']);
```

The Component file is defined as :

```
'use strict';
function ArticleListController($routeParams, articleDataFactory) {
var vm = this;
articleDataFactory.articleDisplay($routeParams.articleId).then(function(response){
console.log(response.data);
vm.article = response.data;
console.log(vm.article);});
}

module('articleDetail').component('articleDetail', {
  templateUrl: 'article-detail/article-detail.template.html',
  controller: ArticleListController
});
```

I have tried every error solution provided over here but the stack trace varies and am unable to understand as to what the issue is. Please guide.

Comment: Search your project for `checkMark`, and if not required, remove it.

Comment: @31piy..It is correct.Removing the filter helped!